# Time series regression with instrument variable

Tags: time-series, econometrics, causality, vector-autoregression, instrumental-variables

I want to know what model I should use to make causal inferences with time series variables with the instrument variable method.

For instance, I want to estimate the effect of price on sales. I have an instrument variable for the price variable. Price and advertisement are endogenous and non-stationary.

$Sale_t = Price_t + Advertisement_t + error_t$

My first thought is difference all the variables and run TSLS. Then I think the potential problem is that the lagged effect of price on sale is not considered.

Should I use a VAR model in this case? Then the question is, how can I use instrument variables in a VAR model?